# "How are you ..." to mean "How can you be ..."

Tags: meaning-in-context

There was a time when most of the people in a room were busy doing something. I heard someone say to someone else,

> How are you standing around doing nothing?

I guessed that the speaker wasn't asking about the way the other person was standing around. I thought what she meant was,

> How can you be standing around doing nothing (while we are so busy)?

My question is, is my guess correct? Can "How are you ...?" be used in place of "How can you be ...?"

Comment: It's not really a matter of whether *How are you ...?* can be used in place of *How can you be ...?* It's really a matter of some people in some contexts asking ***How** [is something happening]?* where *most* people would ask ***Why** [is it happening]?* Personally, I think it's "slangy", and probably best avoided, but one could argue that the usage alludes to "shocked" exclamatory utterances such as ***How dare you**!* and ***How on earth did that happen**?*, so it's potentially useful as a way of conveying annoyance rather than asking a [rhetorical] question.

Comment: Yes. It means what you suspect, OP.

Comment: It might be "How are you? Standing around doing nothing!". The first being a polite greeting. The second being a mild criticism. Together they mean what you suggest.